# How to get chat message when application is not in foreground in Quick Blox?

Tags: android, quickblox

I just started working on Quick Blox. I comepleted chatting when user is online and it works fine. But if application is not in foreground chat message will be not received.

I want show notification about chat message if application is not in foreground.

Comment: You can get it by enable push notification or use impliment chatservice in service

Comment: chat service will be not getting message if we remove it from background. Push notification will be work only if device is offline.

I want call back when device is online and application is removed from background.

Comment: make one sticky service and implement chatservice there

Comment: Can Quick Blox send push notification in this scenario ?

Comment: in my case i always perform logout from chatservice before appclose so i got push